# Source for Modeh Ani

Tags: tefilla, sources-mekorot, shacharis-morning-prayer, morning-day

What is the earliest source that says that one should recite the short prayer of thanks known as "modeh ani" when one gets up in the morning?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/62296/sephardic-chakhamim-mentioning-modeh-ani/62303#62303

Answer (score 5):

Sefer Seder Hayom from [Rabbi Moshe Ben Machir](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%9E%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%A8).First edition (Venezzia) in year שנ"ט" (1599)". See [here](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/42377)

At the [begining of the Sefer](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41230&st=&pgnum=3&hilite=):

> ובקומו מיד מודה אני מלפניך מלך חי וקים שהחזרת בי נשמתי בחמלה רבה אמונתך. ואין צריך לזה נטילת ידיים כי אפילו יהיו דיו מטונפות אין חשש כיון שאינו מזכיר לא שם ולא כינוי. ‏
>
> When he wake up right away "mode ani..." No need to ablutions, even if its hands are soiled, because he had not (yet) mentioned a Name (of Hashem) or a nickname.

In foot note you can read (in an other edition, not the edition in the link):

> הוא הראשון שהביא נוסח המודה אני המקובל בישראל לאמרו בקומו בבוקר, ... , ויש עוד נוסח של מודה אני בסידור רבי קאפיל תלמיד הבעל שם טוב. והוא היה בערך מאתיים שנה אחריו, ולא קבלנו שוסחתו. ‏
>
> He was the first to bring the nussach of Mode Ani that was accepted by Bne Yisrael upon arising... an other version is in the siddur of Rabbi Kapil, pupil of the Baal Shem Tov, which lived aproximately 200 years after Rabbi Moshe Ben Machir, and his nussach is not the widespread version.