Saying Modeh Ani throughout the day
I once heard that a second reason (aside from our hands being impure) why Modeh Ani doesn’t have Hashem’s name in it is so that we can freely say it throughout the day whenever we want to thank Hashem. Does anyone have a source for this and do people actually do this (randomly say Modeh Ani whenever they want to thank Hashem throughout the day)?

Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/73004/ Incidentally, R' Shmuel bar Nachmani (Y'rushalmi B'rachos 29b) mentions two different Modeh Ani prayers (which do include HaShem's name) to be said in the morning and afternoon, respectively. The content of the modern Modeh Ani prayer is a bit different, and more closely parallels the Elokai Neshama prayer (B'rachos 60b). As such, it is a prayer best suited to be recited upon waking.

The modeh ani is a short prayer which is said first thing upon waking in the morning before anything else including washing ones hands or mouth. This is because the level of the soul that the modeh ani is associated with (yechida) can never become impure.
Additionally the lack of God's allows for the prayer to be did when the body is in a state of impurity as when one sleeps an impure spirit is in the body until one's soul is returned. (Kitzur shulchan aruch 2:1)
Though there is some dispute if one has feces on himself or is near the feces of a child that can enough enough solid foods if it is permissible to say it.
After this is said upon waking there isn't an additional reason to say it throughout the day though.
For further reading... https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/modeh-ani/#_ftn20

Not really an answer to the question.
